# The generated exe from chocolatey has their Logo and description. Is there a way to change this?

Tags: c#, chocolatey

I use chocolatey to distribute software and everything works fine, but what bothers me is that the exe-file of my programm then has their Logo and Description set(see Image). Is there a way to change that in the chocolatey installation or is this by default required?

[image: image of exe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was something that was discussed before, you can find that conversation here:

https://github.com/chocolatey-archive/chocolatey/issues/579

Where the actual issues related to the underlying shimgen tools are here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/shimgen/issues/2

and here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/shimgen/issues/4

For the most part, this does work.  Looking through my `chocolatey\bin` folder, I can see a number of shimgen exes that do have the original icon's in place.  The ones that don't seem to be tools that don't actually have their own icons.

Is this actually the case for the tool that you are looking at above?  Does it have it's own icon?

What version of Chocolatey are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 0.10.5.0 and yes it does have it own icon. When you start the exe the correct icon is displayed. Where should i define an icon for the exe? Am i missing something? The icon that is displayed is set in my project,

Comment: Short answer is, it depends.  Assuming that this is your own application that you are creating, it could be that some additional work is required to make it "finable" by shimgen.  Best advice would be to raise an issue in the shimgen repository that I link to above with more information about the application that you are trying to create a shim for.